# How to apply style of selected radiobutton in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, radio-button, vuetify.js, radio-group

I have a doubt, about how to make in Vuetify the border around the v-card (or some other effect, like background color change) when the Radio button is selected.

```
<v-radio @change="setGewitchtsVal('3.5t')" label="3.5t" color="primary" value="3.5t" >
  <template v-slot:label>
    <v-card width="170" color="white" class="trucksicons d-flex align-center flex-column rounded-lg">
    <v-img contain height="60" :src="icon35t"></v-img>
    <span>3.5t</span>
    </v-card>
  </template> 
</v-radio>
```

The current picture of my radiogroup is like this (I removed the radio button pins).

[image: radio button group]

I know, how to make a hover, but not how to highlight selected one.

Comment: How did you hide the radio button pins? I'm working in a similar styling for a form and can't pull that off.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. If someone else arrives to this thread looking for a way to hide the radio button pins, it's as this:
`
<v-radio
            off-icon=""
            on-icon=""
        >
`

Comment: for me, i use css to hide the radio button pins. `.v-input--selection-controls__input {
  display: none !important;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [active-class](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-radio/)

```html
<template>
  <v-radio active-class="active" ...>
  ...
  </v-radio>
</template>

<style scoped>
.active .trucksicons {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this applies to the whole element, not to the v-card. So, I got a big border around v-card with a gaps around it (I have some paddings). And I cannot change the background color of the v-card with this style.

Comment: then select the element you want: `.active .trucksicons`

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to add the "outlined" attribute to the v-card? Otherwise, the border is not visible. To change like this:  :outlined="true" to :outlined="false"

Comment: I found acceptable solution, add this to the v-card: style="box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%)"